# Search for multiple users by email address using admin directory users.list Google API

Tags: google-directory-api

I am trying to use the Admin Directory `users.list` API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list) to query multiple users with their email address.

I can do `query=email=user1@example.com` and I can do `query=email=user2@example.com` but I can't find a way to combine them. None of these work:

- `query=email=user1@example.com OR email=user2@example.com`
- `query=email IN (user1@example.com user2@example.com)`